# React can't define 'then' function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started working with React, and wanted to get data from Django Application with "axios", but I've got an
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oGrRe.png)

Here's my App.js code:

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    notes: [],
  }

  componentNotesData() {
    let data;
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    .then(res => {
      data = res.data;
      then.setState({
        notes: data
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.notes.map((note) => (
            <div>
              <h1>{note.title}</h1>
            </div>
          )
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I was trying to find how to solve this problem in Google, but unfortunately, end up with nothing.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `then.setState()` to do

Comment: @Pointy that should have been `this`, not `then` :)

Comment: You have `then.setState()` in your code, change it to `this.setState()`

Comment: Thank you so much, I thought, that the problem was in "then" function, right after "axios.get()" function. And, I don't know why, I haven't noticed, that I was looking at the wrong line. I had to use "this" function there, instead of "then" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a typo. Like the error, `then` is not defined. I believe you wanted to use `this`:

```
this.setState(...)
```